# Issue with /restart and slot

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have developed a bot and created a custom action, where I will take input from the users and store their input in slots. Later the input will be used for authentication.

The problem is when the action against the slot is triggered, the `/restart` action doesn’t work. I want to clear the log when /restart action is called. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a Github issue for this [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/5205); relevant comment from [IgNoRaNt23](https://github.com/IgNoRaNt23) :

> "The problem here is the action prediction. There are at least two policies in play, the MappingPolicy, which handles the restart action and the FormPolicy for any FormAction. Both policies predict their action with a confidence of 1.0 in your case, but the FormPolicy has a higher priority than the MappingPolicy, which means that the FormPolicy always wins. So no restart may be triggered, if the form is never left. Which may happen, when you have 'self_from_text'-mapping for your slot."

Comment: Thanks for your responce, but this reply in the issue didnt solve the problem, thats why posted in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I think what you're running into might actually be a bug so watching github for fixes - or contributing one - might be your best option. Or you can try what IgNoRaNt23 mentioned about a custom policy.